# Tensorflow Object-Detection Fine-Tuning leads to incorrect accuracy values

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I am working with the Tensorflow Object-Detection [API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and want to use a pre-trained Faster R-CNN Resnet101 model on Kitti image data and fine-tune it on Cityscapes image data. I downloaded the pre-trained model [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#kitti-trained-models).

This [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py) creates the tfrecord files. I use this script to create tfrecord files from Cityscape (CS) images.

The CS tf_records are afterward used in order to fine-tune the pre-trained Resnet model. For this task, I use [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-training-job)

```
python3.5 model_main.py --pipeline_config_path={Path to config file in ../samples/configs/} --model_dir={Output directory} --num_train_steps={Train Steps} --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --alsologtostderr
```

Using only CS Training and Validation data lead to an COCO accuracy of -1.000

```
Average Precision (AP) @[ IoU=0.5:0.95 | area=all | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000
....
```

I tried different things:

1. Train on CS data and validate on Kitti data. This lead to an COCO accuracy that is not -1.000 but very low. Between 0.01 and 1.5% (after 10.000 training steps)
2. Looked at Tensorboard visualizations. The loss falls from 0.05 to 0.01 over the first 1.500 iterations and stays over the last 8.500 iterations around 2.5e-4 and does not change much. (I would upload an image if I would know how..)
3. Fine-tuned the pre-trained model with manipulated Kitti data. I changed the content of the tfrecord files that create the Kitti tfrecord files. By this, I mean I deleted all of the useless variables (like 3D Annotations and so on) in the tfrecord data in order to have similar content to the CS tfrecords I created (code below). Using these manipulated Kitti data also lead to a validation accuracy that seems to be normal (around 70-80%). Therefore, I expect that this error is not caused by an missing attribute in the tfrecords.
4. An inference of the CS data on the pre-trained Resnet model leads to an accuracy around 20% and this is what I expect. Kitti inference leads to an accuracy around 85%.

Using CS tfrecords with the following content per image:

```
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
    'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf8')),
    'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf8')),
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
    'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format.encode('utf8')),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
    'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult_obj),
    'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example
```

Using this code to encode an image

```
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(image_path, '{}'.format(currentImageName)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_image_data = fid.read()

    encoded_image_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_image_data)
```

Could the coding of the data be the reason? Or what could be another source for an error? As mentioned, I tried several things and none of them worked as expected. Fine-tuning should not be that hard or do I miss any point?

As mentioned in point 4, I tested the inference and the tf_record files and therefore, I expect that it is possible to fine-tune the model.

In general, I expect that the accuracy is not close to 0% after 10.000 iterations.

Everything looks a bit strange and I do not know what the error is. Therefore, I would appreciate each hint/remark/solution for this issue.

---

EDIT:

```
def create_tf_example(currentName, anno_path, image_path):

    currentNameSplit = currentName.split('.')[0]
    currentImageName = currentNameSplit + '.png'

    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(image_path, '{}'.format(currentImageName)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_image_data = fid.read()

    encoded_image_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_image_data)
    image = Image.open(encoded_image_io)
    image = np.asarray(image)

    width = int(image.shape[1])
    height = int(image.shape[0])

    filename = os.path.join(image_path, '{}'.format(currentImageName))
    image_format = 'png' # b'jpeg' or b'png'

    with open(anno_path + currentName) as file: 
        lines = file.readlines()

        xmins = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
        xmaxs = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box
         # (1 per box)
        ymins = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
        ymaxs = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box
         # (1 per box)
        classes_text = [] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
        classes = [] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)


        for li in range(len(lines)): 
            print('Lines[li]: {}'.format(lines[li]))
            xmins.append(float(lines[li].split()[0]) / width)
            xmaxs.append(float(lines[li].split()[2]) / width)
            ymins.append(float(lines[li].split()[1]) / height)
            ymaxs.append(float(lines[li].split()[3]) / height)
            classID = lines[li].split()[4]
            if int(classID) == 0:
                className = 'Car'
                classes_text.append(className.encode('utf8'))
                classID = 0
                classes.append(classID+1) # add 1 because class 0 is always reserved for 'background'
            elif int(classID) == 1:
                className = 'Person'                
                classes_text.append(className.encode('utf8'))
                classID = 1
                classes.append(classID+1)
            else:
                print('Error with Image Annotations in {}'. format(currentName))

        difficult_obj = [0] * len(xmins)


    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
    'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf8')),
    'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf8')),
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
    'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format.encode('utf8')),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
    'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult_obj),
    'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example



def main(_):

    writer_training = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path_Training)
    writer_valid = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path_Test)
    writer_test = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path_Valid)

    allAnnotationFiles = []
    os.chdir(FLAGS.anno_path)
    for file in sorted(glob.glob("*.{}".format('txt'))):
        allAnnotationFiles.append(file)

    counter=0
    for currentName in allAnnotationFiles:
        if counter < 2411:
            tf_example = create_tf_example(currentName, FLAGS.anno_path, FLAGS.image_path)
            writer_training.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
            counter += 1

        elif counter > 2411 and counter < 2972:
            tf_example = create_tf_example(currentName, FLAGS.anno_path, FLAGS.image_path)
            writer_valid.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
            counter += 1

        elif counter <= 3475:
            tf_example = create_tf_example(currentName, FLAGS.anno_path, FLAGS.image_path)
            writer_test.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
            counter += 1 


    writer_training.close()
    writer_test.close()
    writer_valid.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: This looks like an error from the tfrecord file (dataset), so that when you fine-tune your model, the accuracy is -1.00 (the average precision value of -1 is the default value, this is usually caused by absent categories.), and when you validate it on Kitti dataset, the model is so badly tuned that lead to very low accuracy.  It would be great if you can provide one image data with corresponding label file, then we can find if the problem existed in the tfrecord (Only the create_tfrecord script is not enough, it should come together with the dataset).

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? I am using image data saved as png images and per image file I have a txt annotations file with the schema: x1, y1, x2, y2, classID
In a next step, I extract these information and build the tfrecord file. 
I would upload the file to extract the information and build the tfrecord. However, this is too long for this comment section.

Comment: I added the code to create the tfrecord files in the original post. Would be great if you could check it if you find an error. Mainly, I followed the official tutorial provided by Tensorflow and the the GitHub Repo for the racoon dataset (https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py)

Comment: the script looks fine to me.  However I still don't know what does the content of the txt file looks like, for example, if the coordinates are in absolute format or normalized format. (In the script it is assumed that coordinates are in absolute format)

Comment: You are right! For each image, there is one txt file with the annotations. Each file contains for each object in the image (car or pedestrian) one line with 5 entries separated by a space. The 4 coordinates of the bounding box are represented by absolut coordinates and the class label is 0 or 1 (according to the class). 

Do you have any idea what is wrong that produces the error I mentioned?

Comment: No, I did not find anything wrong with it. But I think you can try using the pretrained Kitti model to run evaluation on your CS tfrecord. You can check this tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/oid_inference_and_evaluation.md.   If the evaluation makes sense, probably it is not the error of tfrecords but some other steps are wrong.

Comment: I already did this (I mentioned it in point 4 where I describe what I have done). The accuracy on the CS data is around 20% (most of the objects are detected but many small objects are missed therefore the low accuracy). Inference on the Kitti data lead to an accuracy around 80%. If evaluation and training require the same information in the tfrecord, this should not be the error. 
Do you have any idea what else could be wrong? I use the same config as Kitti but changed the paths to the tfrecord files. Everything else should be the same. I do not know what else could be wrong... just weird..

Comment: Sorry missed that point. Unfortunately I did not have any clue what went wrong either.

Comment: Nevertheless thanks for your time you spent on this topic. 
I have some further ideas, maybe you can tell me which of them are the most likeliest ones to try: 
- I saw the class labels/texts in tfrecord are handed over in [..] - I hand them over without 
- pull again the repo - I changed some lines of code in order to make the OD work (according to comments on Github)
- change the hyperparameters in the config

Any further ideas what I could change to make the OD work for this dataset..?
Normally, I expect it to work with any input data and not only for the Kitti image data...

Comment: Something messed up: There are three options: 1) change class text/label 2) Pull Repo 3) Change Config file. 

Furthermore, I have another issue: Is the way I describe for the fine-tuning the correct one or do I have to make further steps. Is a re-initialization of the last layer necessary or does this happening automatically in the code?

Comment: Figured it out! I had a mismatch between the class labels in the tfrecord file and the class labels in the label map file. "Car" vs "car"...

Comment: Glad to hear that.